# security- Idevice ios ipsw

Tags: ios, iphone, security, checksum

Okay I am working on modding ios firmware 9.3.5 with removed setup files. I was able to mod the files while maintaining all apple signitures and encryption. however somewhere in the files is a stock checksum value of what the file should be. I have narrowed it down to either the kernal cache or inside the firmware folder somewhere. I have tried using a hex editor to read the binary of the kernel cache however couldn't figure out if this checksum was writen here. Does anyone know where this checksum is stored so i can change the value and be able to push the modded firmware to the device? Any help would be very helpful. I know device doesn't obtain this information from the internet as i completely disconnected from the internet before attempting to push to the device.

Comment: however down voted this question either does not know anything about ios security. As Im finding out it does an intial md5 checksum of the compressed files before extracting. then checks the md5 checksum of individual files against stored checksum values inside the build manifest file that tells the kernel what file goes where, the checksum value, the key, actions to take with conditions.  inital compressed ipsw checksum is cross checked with the apple servers, all others from stored checksum values.

Comment: Continued: If you delete Any files, you must change the stored checksum value of that file inside the build manifest file. Then in order to pass the inital checksum cross check from apple. your modded ipsw file must be exactly the same size which is achieved by making a text document with text.  You keep adding or subtracting text until the full compressed ipsw firmware file is the exact size as the orginal duplicating the md5 checksum.  If done correctly you trick itunes to push the firmware to device and installing your .dmg files. Everything must be Exact down to the byte.

Answer (score 0):

the digest of the checksums is found inside the build Manifest. Ended up doing a mass search through C# program that opened all files and checked for the checksum value. Ended up being in the build Manifest